# how to pass a parameter containing & to a bat file from cygwin bash

Tags: shell, batch-file, cygwin

Here's a simple bat file:

```
C:\temp>type a.bat
@echo off
rem try
echo %1
```

With some difficulty, I am able to pass `a&b` as parameter to it:

```
C:\temp>a.bat a&b
a
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\temp>a.bat "a&b"
"a&b"
```

The paramater has the `"` character; I can live with it. But I can't figure out how to call it from a cygwin shell:

```
C:\temp>c:\cygwin\bin\sh
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a&b
[1] 7760
a
sh: b: command not found
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a\&b
a
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[1]+  Done                    ./a.bat a
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat \"a\&b\"
"\"a
'b\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat "a\&b"
a\
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: from your tries only `a\&b` makes sense.. and should work.. weird

Comment: the rest are random acts of desparation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows CMD uses `^` to escape most special characters. So you can use that to pass your argument without enclosing quotes.

```
C:\temp>a.bat a^&b
```

But the parameter that is received will be `a&b`. Your batch script will give an error when it attempts to ECHO the value of %1 because the `&` is not quoted or escaped.

You could safely echo the value if you enclose it in quotes:

```
echo "%1"
```

But if you pass the value already enclosed in quotes `"a&b"`, then you get an error again. That is why many batch script use the `~` modifier to remove any existing enclosing quotes (if they exist), and then explicitly add quotes. The following will work if the value of %1 is quoted or unquoted.

```
echo "%~1"
```

You still can have problems with something like `"a&b"&c`, but that is another story :-)

Another option would be to double escape the `&` in the original command line:

```
C:\temp>a.bat a^^^&b
```

Your batch script will recieve `a^&b`, and then the echo will work.

With regard to Cygwin, I know very  little, but I believe I mostly understand tests 1, 2 and 3.

Test 1:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a&b
[1] 7760
a
sh: b: command not found
```

Cygwin is passing `a` to your batch script and failing to execute command `b`

Test 2:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a\&b
a
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm not sure if CMD parses the command line passed from Cygwin before the batch script is executed or not.

If so, then `a` is getting passed to your batch script, and then CMD.EXE is failing to execute `b`.

If not, then Cygwin is successfully executing your script and passing `a&b`, but your ECHO statement is failing as I explained earlier.

One of the following should work with your script, but I'm not sure which:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a^\&b
or
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat a^^^\&b
```

One of the above will pass `a^&b` and your ECHO should work.

Test 3:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat \"a\&b\"
"\"a
'b\""' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have no idea what Cygwin is doing. Somehow it is introducing additional double quotes.

Test 4:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat "a\&b"
a\
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Cygwin strips the quotes, and the backslash is preserved. Again, either the `&` is causing problems when CMD.EXE is launching the script, or it is causing problems within the script when you ECHO it.

One of the following should work, passing `a^&b` to your script. I'm just not sure which one:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat "a^&b"
or
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat "a^^^&b"
```

---

I believe the following will successfully pass `"a&b"` to your script:

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat '"a&b"'
```

I also think the following will do the same, though I am not as confident due to the result of Test 3.

```
sh-4.1$ ./a.bat "\"a&b\""
```

Comment: If my bat file echoes `"%1"` instead of `%1` then ` ./a.bat a^\&b` and ` ./a.bat "a^&b"` both print `"a&b"`. I haven't tried other options yet, thanks for the `^` escape char reminder.